# How to keep a Swift loop running indefinitely (forever)?

Tags: ios, swift, primes, func

I have written a function which currently displays all of the prime numbers under 1000.

I can keep making 1000 bigger to generate more numbers, but I do not know how to make it keep going on forever once run.

```
func generatePrimes() {
    let numbers = 2...1000
    for n in numbers {
        var prime = true

        for i in 2..<n { 
            if n % i == 0 {
                prime = false
                break
            }
        }

        if prime == true {
            print(n)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a `while` loop with the argument being `true`. That way, the loop would never end.

```
func generatePrimes() {
    var n = 2
    while true {
        var prime = true

        for i in 2..<n { 
            if n % i == 0 {
                prime = false
                break
            }
        }

        if prime == true {
            print(n)
        }

        n += 1
    }
}
```

Note that we use a variable (`n`) and increment (add 1 to it) on each iteration of the while loop.

If you want it to end when it hits some `n`, you can have a conditional that checks against `n` and `break`'s out of the loop:

```
var n = 2
while true {
    if n == 1000 {
        break
    }
    n += 1
}
```

The above code will stop execution when `n` hits `1000` and will not print anything for that case.

Comment: You can improve your code quality by removing statements like `if prime == true` and replacing them with `if prime`, for easier readability and maintainability of your code.

Comment: Altho it's nice to teach the `break` keyword, in this case it would be a bad usage.
`while true` should be set to `while n != 1000`

Answer (score 1):

Use a `while` loop instead of `for` loop. It can also be done with a `for` loop, but `for` loop is preferred when you know the number or range of the iterations you are performing. If you're using a while loop you just have to set the condition for the loop, in this case you need to specify the condition as true since you want the loop to run forever.

Just replace your `for` loop in your code with `while`. It should look something like this

```
while(true)
{
    if n % i == 0 {
        prime = false
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: Please expand your answer.

Comment: They would need to increment `n`.  Eventually they will get an integer overflow

Comment: @Paulw11: On a 64-bit platform that would take several years if you process 10^6 integers per second :)

Comment: Yeah, but that isn't "forever" ;).  The question itself is fundamentally flawed.

Answer (score 0):

You also can build an unconditional infinite loop using `do {}` block and `continue` statement.

```
AGAIN:
do {
    print("step...")
    continue AGAIN
}
```

Comment: it looks much better than `while true { }` but how to break such cycle if necessary?

Answer (score -4):

```
func generatePrimes() {

    var prime = true

    let numbers = 2...1000
    for n in numbers {

        prime = true

        if n == 2 || n == 3 {
            print(n)
        } else {
            for i in 2..<n-1 {
                if n % i == 0 {
                    //not prime numbers
                    prime = false
                }
            }
            if prime == true {
                print(n)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can do it like this. Just exclude 1 and n.